# How to submit a form in RichFaces?

Tags: forms, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I know it maybe sounds a basic question but I'm having a hard time figuring this out. 
First of all I have this form:

```
<h:form>
   <h:inputText value="#{movies.name}"/>
   <a4j:commandButton id="mybutton" value="Modify" immediate="true" action="#{movies.testModify}"/>
</h:form>
```

I want to catch the value from the input text from within my testModify() method from movies bean. 
My problem is that testModify doesn't get called at all. The odd behaviour that I noticed is that when I remove h:form tag the method does get called but I still don't know how to get the value from my input text.

From what I've read, a4j:commandButton needs h:form for it to work properly.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I discovered what the problem was: I accidentaly wrapped the h:form inside another h:form. After removing the parent h:form the call to the method worked perfectly and furthermore, the name property was in place. So, in conclusion, a4j:commandButton does the job very good.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `h:commandButton` instead of an `a4j:commandButton`. The first is the standard JSF button that will submit your form, the latter performs an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as stated by [Markos Fragkakis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125713/markos-fragkakis), use a basic `<h:commandButton>` instead of an ajaxified `<a4j:commandButton>`, as in your case, you have no interest of using an Ajax action here.

Second, remove the `immediate="true"` attribute on this button. Using this attribute [means that](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/commandButton.jsf?tab=info&cid=73244) the default ActionListener should be executed immediately (i.e. during `Apply Request Values` phase of the request processing lifecycle), rather than waiting until the `Invoke Application` phase.

If your action on Java bean is still not called, maybe something wrong happend before the `Invoke Application` JSF [lifecycle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/) [phase](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSFIntro10.html). Adding a `<h:messages>` will display the possible issues:

```
<h:form>
   <h:messages/>
   <h:inputText value="#{movies.name}"/>
   <h:commandButton id="mybutton" value="Modify" action="#{movies.testModify}"/>
</h:form>
```